# jukebox installation: llvmlite wheel build failed

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-api, llvmlite

I am currently trying to install OpenAI's Jukebox codebase (https://github.com/openai/jukebox) for my bachelor FYP.

Specifically, I am trying to `%pip install` it on a Colab notebook, following a tutorial for an alternative use of jukebox that can be found here: https://github.com/p-lambda/jukemir.

The issue is, installation of some of the requirements fails no matter what I try

At first, I simply followed the second linked tutorial, hence running

```
%pip install git+https://github.com/openai/jukebox.git
```

However, installation fails and throws the following error:

[image: error log]

It seems that for some reason the `.whl` file for llvmlite cannot be built. Weirdly enough, running

```
import llvmlite
llvmlit.__version__
```

outputs
`0.39.1`, as if the following uninstallation of llvmlite was not succesful

I tried to install the packages in `requirements.txt` individually, and the problem seems to appear when I try to intall `numba==0.48.0`

Thank you all in advance for your help